# Google Maps Api using Math.random to get random location - JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having trouble getting my map to go to a random location. I want it to go to a random location between the bounds (lat -85 to 85, lng -180 to 180). Whenever the button is clicked the function makes the map grey.

```
function random(lat, lng){
var random = new google.maps.LatLng((Math.random()-85)*85+, (Math.random()-180)*180));
map.panTo(random);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var random = new google.maps.LatLng( (Math.random()*(85*2)-85), (Math.random()*(180*2)-180) );
```

try with something like this,
or more generally:

```
function randomBetween(min, max) {
if (min < 0) {
    return min + Math.random() * (Math.abs(min)+max);
}else {
    return min + Math.random() * max;
}}
```